# Drag and Drop upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I want to make drag and drop upload. User drops the files on div, and when he clicks on upload button, they are sent to server.
javascript unfortunatelly does not know what variable fd is. How I can pass that variable to DragAndDropUpload() function.. Not sure if that is the  real problem..

Im wondering whether to show you my website or not :D

here is my code(only important things , I removed the other things to make code look smaller)

Should I pass fd to function as an argument? o.O or what

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fd;
    var drag_area = $("#drag_and_drop_div");

    drag_area.on('drop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nahraj_button").show();
        $("#upload_button").attr('onclick','DragAndDropUpload()');
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; 
        fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file[]',files[0]);
    });
});

function DragAndDropUpload(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'uploader.php');
    request.send(fd);
}
```

EDIT: Console shows this: Uncaught Reference error: fd is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the scope of the variable `fd`. You define it within the scope of `$(document).ready(function(){});` and later expect it to be set inside of your function `DragAndDropUpload()`. This will not work. You should pass it in the function.

You also mixed up your events. You define the one event listener (for click) when the user drops something. You should do that outside.

I don't know if the rest of your code is ok since you didn't include everything I need to know to answer that. Always say exactly which plugin you are using and which third-party scripts.

And if you want to show something but not your website, use jsfiddle or codepen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Document is ready, no user action yet
  var fd; // the fd variable sits inside the $(document).ready(function(){}) scope
  var drag_area = $("#drag_and_drop_div");

  drag_area.on('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#nahraj_button").show();
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files; 
    fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file[]',files[0]); 
  });

  $("#upload_button").attr('onclick', function() {
    // now call you function and pass the form data as an argument
    DragAndDropUpload(fd);
  });

});

function DragAndDropUpload(data)
{
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'uploader.php');
  request.send(data);
}
```

[This article](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/) explains variable scopes in javascript a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

The most immediate problem I see with your code here, and this is what would be triggering the error in the console, is that you define the variable `fd` inside of the onReady event handler. Thus, the variable is out of scope inside of the function DragAndDropUpload.

The solution to this is to pass `fd` to `DragAndDropUploader` as an argument. To do this, you'll want to create a parameter, or variable passed to your function that can be used inside of the function, when defining the function.

Try defining DragAndDropUpload like so:

```
function DragAndDropUpload(fd) { 
    //Your code here. 
}
```

Then, you can call that function from any function that has access to the the fd variable (which, in this case, I'm assuming to be the onReady event listener), and pass to it the variable fd. DragAndDropUpload will then be able to do with that variable whatever it needs to!

Also, in the future, you may want to consider providing an example of your project using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/), which lets people see your code in a more interactive and complete state.